# Postgres UUID reference overhead

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider this table used to store object metadata

```
CREATE TABLE meta (
  "obj_uuid"  uuid,
  "type"      int,
  "value"     text
);
```

Objects are identified using `uuid`s as primary keys, the metadata row references that `uuid`. Now I am concerned this will blow up the DB size exponentially.

Does Postgres optimize this on itself, or would it be better to create an intermediate table that maps the `uuid` to a `serial` and reference this serial in the metadata table instead?

Comment: If a serial is adequate then why are you using uuid?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto because the UUID comes from CouchDB

Comment: This question on DBA.StackExchange might help you out. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/322/what-are-the-drawbacks-with-using-uuid-or-guid-as-a-primary-key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I am concerned this will blow up the DB size exponentially

A uuid is only 128 bits, as compared to a 64-bit `bigint` or 32-bit `integer`. So your worst case overhead is 4x the space for the key.

If your key/value pairings are very small and there are a great deal of them this might be a concern. In that case I'd use an `integer` or `biginteger` key based on a `sequence`, then just use the `uuid` as a unique secondary key that doesn't appear in referential integrity checks.

Comment: Actually, using UUID might save space in this case. Currently it takes 64b (main table) + 64b (PK index) + 64b (ref table). In the case you suggested it will take 32 + 64 (main table uuid + serial) 32 + 64 (serial and uniq indexes) + 32 (ref table).

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko UUIDs are 128 bits, not 64. Yes, if it was a 1:1 master to ref table relationship there'd be no benefit, but if there are many `meta` rows per main row it'll start making a big difference in a hurry. With `128 + n*128` vs `(128+32) + n*(32)`, the latter wins even with n=1, though the complexity wouldn't be worth it until you start having several meta rows per main row. There's a *lot* less benefit if you need `bigint` keys for your main rows, to the point where I doubt I'd bother unless I had tens or hundreds of meta rows per main row; you need nearly n=10 to make 2:1.